# How can I update updateNotes first then getNotes?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

Here it's logging first getNotes then updateNotes

[image]

is there a way to first updateNotes then getNotes? Because when I edit and click the left Arrow icon it's not updating changes unless I refresh the page.

Here is the code from NotesPage.js

```
const NotesPage = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
    console.log('Log from getNotes');
  }, [])

  const getNotes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/notes");
    const data = await response.json()
    setNotes(data)
  }
```

and here is the code from NotePage.js

```
function NotePage({ match, history }) {
  const noteId = match.params.id;
  const [note, setNote] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getNote();
    console.log("Log from getNote");
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [noteId]);

  const getNote = async () => {
    if (noteId === 'new') return
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/notes/${noteId}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    setNote(data);
  };

  const updateNote = async () => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/notes/${noteId}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ ...note, "updated": new Date() }),
    });
    console.log("Log from updateNote");
  };

  const handeSubmit = () => {
    if (noteId !== "new" && !note.body) {
      deleteNote();
    } else if (noteId !== "new") {
      updateNote();
    } else if (noteId === 'new' && note !== null) {
      createNote()
    }
    history.push("/");
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Try getNotes after doing all other actions**

Like so:

```
const handeSubmit = async () => {
  if (noteId !== "new" && !note.body) {
    await deleteNote();
  } else if (noteId !== "new") {
    await updateNote();
  } else if (noteId === "new" && note !== null) {
    await createNote();
  }
  getNote();
};
```